# How do I make PHP interpret faster than NodeJS?

Tags: php, node.js, performance, asynchronous, synchronous

I get the asynchronous advantage that comes with NodeJS (and PHP with Swoole), but why is NodeJS so monstrously faster than PHP in a purely single-core, single process, synchronous use case?

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$j = 0;
$start_time = time();
for($i = 0; $i <= 1000000000; $i++){
    $j += $i;
}
$total_time = time() - $start_time;
echo $j."\n";
echo "Total Time: ".$total_time."\n";
?>
```

which executes in 41 seconds

And here's my NodeJS code:

```
console.time("elapsed");

var i;
var j = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++){
    j += i;
}

console.log(j);
console.timeEnd("elapsed");
```

that executes in 2.9 seconds

Comment: Because of different languages performs different internal actions. Also, what versions of PHP and Node you compare?

Comment: Because many large companies have poured tons of resources into optimising the JS engine, because it runs on hundreds of millions of partly low-powered devices…

Comment: @Justinas PHP 7.4.9 and NodeJS 14.9.0. Can you please elaborate what "internal actions" you're mentioning, that is the purpose of my question. I need to understand the internal dynamics of these two languages on different hardware.

Comment: @Turab PHP is converted to C code - internal code

Comment: @Justinas I converted the script to C code and it takes 4 seconds to execute. Why does PHP take 40 seconds if it converts to C code? What happens during that conversion that the execution time lengthens?

Comment: An `int` in PHP is probably not a pure C `int`, but a C object which adds reference counting for garbage collection and such.

Comment: Modern Javascript engines have JIT optimisers that trigger once they detected a certain piece of code has been executed *n* times in a short time, and will optimise the hell out of that piece of code in the background, then hot-swap it into the running program. I.e., especially your 1000000000x loop will trigger that specific part of the compiler. PHP on the other hand will just keep running its more inefficient code 1000000000 times.

Comment: What is the result you get for `j` in both version? Note that languages don't behave the same way when dealing with big values (talking about the difference between 4s of converted in C vs the 2.9 for JS)

Comment: @Kaddath
C: -243309312
JS: 500000000067109000
PHP:500000000500000000

Thanks for bringing this up. C does output a negative value whereas JS outputs a value that's closer to the real sum. However, PHP's sum seems to be the most accurate.

Do you think these output values have an impact on performance?

Comment: It's probably a minor factor, considering that there are so many things that can differ between different machines and languages implementations, and cache usage that plays a role (I know that PHP can re-use generated C code in conditions that change between versions/settings), for example your PHP code runs in 9 or 10 seconds in [TIO](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJUvBVsHAmkuluCSxqCS@JDM3FSgAojQ0rbnS8os0VDLBKhSAtI2tgqEBDIBEtLU1q7kUgABojLYtUMCaq5ZLpSS/JDEH1SgFXQUkG6y5UpMz8oGa9JRi8pSgPKUQkDaFEKC8lYKSHpIpEFX//wMA). But repeated 1 billion times it has an impact